# configuring .htaccess file with multiple subdomains Justhost

Tags: ruby-on-rails, .htaccess, subdomain

Situation is like this :

1. I have hosting company justhost.com
2. There I have main domain and two subdomains. First subdomain is with PHP
   based webpage, but second is newly created and based on ruby on
   rails.

I want such thing, before I am sure that newly created application on RoR is functioning well, keep old one up and running. But somehow when I want modify .htaccess file with code for RoR (source- https://my.justhost.com/cgi/help/rails#access ).

**main htacces file located on root_page :**

```
DirectoryIndex index.html index.shtml index.xhtml index.wml index.perl index.pl index.plx index.ppl index.cgi index.jsp index.js index.jp index.php4 index.php3 index.php index.phtml index.htm home.htm default.htm index.fcgi default.html
# -FrontPage-


<Limit GET POST>
order deny,allow
deny from all
allow from all
</Limit>
<Limit PUT DELETE>
order deny,allow
deny from all
</Limit>
AuthUserFile /home/ecotec11/public_html/_vti_pvt/service.pwd
AuthGroupFile /home/ecotec11/public_html/_vti_pvt/service.grp
ErrorDocument 404 /404.shtml

AuthName ecotechno.lv
IndexIgnore .htaccess */.??* *~ *# */HEADER* */README* */_vti*
```

htacces file for RoR application:

```
Options -MultiViews
            PassengerResolveSymlinksInDocumentRoot on
            #Change to your environment
            RailsEnv production
            RailsBaseURI /$HOME/$USER/eco
            SetEnv GEM_HOME /
```

This is what I get :
http://gyazo.com/291394024c60284e315b04b3b91128f4 :

It seems that project can't find installed gems or valid rails installation. I tried to update rails installation, but now when it succeded there is no change at all.

Thanks